# mac MAMP driver PHP for MongoDB : class Mongo don't found

Tags: php, mongodb, mamp

I want to install PHP driver for MongoDB with MAMP, but all my tests miss (I have read and tried many pages stackerflow).
I installed MongoDB works in the terminal.
MAMP works.
To install the PHP driver, I tried:

> http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.osx

For :

```
$ sudo /Applications/MAMP//bin/php/php5.6.7 pecl install mongo
```

I have : `

> fatal error: 'php.h'` file not found

I try : 
When I put `phpinfo ();` in my php code, I have the correct page:
but when i try to login with a php page, I get the error:
What to do ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

he finally seems much easier to use mongo with php present on mac. To install php: http://www.grafikart.fr/tutoriels/mac-os/yosemite-apache-php-mysql-524 (French). Mongo then operates without added.